# Blackberry in Telerik AppBuilder

Tags: blackberry-10, kendo-mobile, telerik-appbuilder

I have a kendo mobile application developed using Telerik AppBuilder extension for Visual Studio. I can see the output in AppBuilder simulator for iphone, android phones and windows phone. Now I want to see the result in blackberry phone. I know Telerik does not have support for blackberry in current Icenium. But is there any other option in which I can run my kendo mobile application in blackberry phone or any simulator?

```
Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

For simulation purposes you can use the [Ripple emulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) - it's not great, but it does support BB10. To create a build you can follow the [Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html#BlackBerry%2010%20Platform%20Guide).